# How to generate multiple parse trees for ambiguous input in ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm facing an ambiguous case where the input string could be parsed using different rules, I need to consider both options and generate multiple parse trees for them.

For simplicity, considering a person name like "Alber Johanson", this name could be parsed as

```
(fullName (firstName Alber) (lastName Johanson))
```

or parsed as

```
(fullName (firstName Alber) (lastName Johan) (relation son))
```

First, how the rules could be configured to handle the second case? As it's part of the second string and not a separate token.

Second, how to generate parse trees for all possible options for the input string?

**UPDATE**

This is a sample of the grammar that I have, it could be used only to parse the first case but not the second one

```html
fullName: firstName lastName | firstName lastName relation;
firstName: NAME;
lastName: NAME;
relation: REL;

NAME: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
REL: 'son';

WHITESPACE : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u0020' | '\u000C' )+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: to answer your question about _how the rules could be configured_ it is totally your(application) decision(requirement)! we'll at least need to know how a name should be split in your application? Johanson should be split as **Johan** and **son**? what other rules? we need to know more about what you have tried in an effort to develop your application.

Comment: @user3320018 I updated my question with the grammar that I have

Comment: Do you want to handle the cases differently or why do you want to generate multiple parse trees?

Comment: The answer by @CoronA is right; you can't do what you want, but that's because of the lexer.  You have a deeper problem, which is producing multiple parse interpretations. ANTLR isn't designed to do that, and bending to do so is likely to be very hard.   You might consider using a GLR parser instead; they are designed to produce all possible parses.   A GLR parser won't fix your lexing problem; you need to decide what you want to do about that first.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard yes I want to gather all the possible options for the name structure to be handled later in my application

Comment: @IraBaxter which is better for my second question? GEP parser as CoronA recommended or the GLR parser? I don't know much about either of them

Comment: @vanilla: you mean "PEG"?  Peg is a backtracking parser.  If it tries an alternative that doesn't work, it may backtrack to some other valid point in the space of valid prefixes for the language, but it backtracks on *failure* to match.  If it succeeds on an alternative, it doesn't try anything else.  So it will not enumerate all possible matches of your input, and thus cannot capture all parses.  GLR parsers, however, explore/generate all possible parses, and return a DAG instead of a tree, where the sharing corresponds to identical subtrees under alternative parses ("ambiguities").

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for your feedback. yes, sorry I mean "PEG" :) . do you know a good library that I can use as a GLR parser generator in java?  and why the GLR parser cannot fix the lexing problem, does it require and external lexer or does it not designed to handle similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR will not allow you to do it the way you want. Yet the reason is not ambiguity, but the tokenizer.

The word "Johanson" is always lexed as NAME, because of the ANTLR lexing policy:

- return the Token with the longest match
- in case of two tokens matching have the same length prefer the first defined

The token `REL` will never occur, since

- any word with suffix 'son' is a `NAME` (longest match)
- any word with prefix 'son' is a `NAME` (longest match)
- yet an isolated word 'son' is a `NAME` (`REL` matches but is not first defined)

**Answer to your first question:**
It cannot be handled by the ANTLR parser, because it relies on tokenizing before parsing. You have two options:

- use parser generator allowing you to tokenize parser directed (PEG-Parsers like parboiled, rats should do it)
- discard the token REL, and reparse last names while visiting the parse tree

**Answer to your second question:**

Both alternatives above make it hard to solve the question of printing the possible interpretations of the same char sequence.

PEG-Parsers are designed to prefer the first alternative by design, it will not explore further if a valid interpretation is found.

ANTLR yet is not designed to drive the lexer directed by the parser. If you decide to reparse the lastnames, it is probably easier to find the interpretation with pure java than writing a new lexer/parser to find them.

Comment: thanks for your elaborated answer. I'll try to check PEG parser.

Answer (score 2):

Switching from a long stream of comments:

As long as you define lexemes to pick up whole words, and have a policy about which lexeme wins when two are recognized, you will have this problem.

To avoid it, you have to have lexemes that don't compete.  What you can do is to run a GLR parser with *characters* as lexemes; for the short inputs (e.g., person names) this won't be any kind of problem.  Then you can define your name rule in the grammar rather than as a lexeme recognizer,and the GLR parser will offer all the possible interpretations.

No, I don't know of a good Java-based GLR parser.  There's a big list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators